# Semiconductor industry specific journals for applied data science - Low to Med impact factor

Tags: publications, research-process, paper-submission, computer-science, bibliometrics

Am working in a semiconductor industry as a emerging data scientist. As part of my task, I work on simple problems and solve them using simple algorithms such as traditional machine algos - SVM, Random Forests, Logistic Regression, ARIMA time series etc.

However, if I would like to publish my work (with my manager approval), what are some of the low to medium impact factor semiconductor industry specific journals that I can aim for?

While you may feel that it may not be of no use to the scientific community if I am solving simple problems using simple algorithms, I just want to get started with my scientific writing and publishing projects (as papers) mainly to improve my job prospects (to stand out from the crowd) and also because I believe that projects that we do, people may benefit from my experience.

Is there any semi-conductor specific journal list (low-medium) that you can share for time-series, shallow ML based projects etc? So, I can know what kind of projects are done in the industry, understand the research gaps and try to fill in the gaps using my work

Comment: I don't know anything about the semiconductor industry specifically, unfortunately. If you do forecasting, then you might want to take a look at [*Foresight*](https://forecasters.org/foresight/) (I'm a deputy editor). Alternatively, it's usually best to look at what kind of journals you yourself or your peers read. Do you have any academic contacts that might be able to point you to something?

Comment: This seems to be a "shopping question".

Comment: @StephanKolassa - I work with sales managers and demand planners in my job. As we are backward in the methods that we use, I want to improve the methods that we use, publish to larger audience, get feedback (by reviewers) etc. My organization don't expect me to do this. But I wish to do this to learn, add value to my resume as data scientist. For ex, I see in Healthcare some journals like "applied clinical informatics" focus on application of existing methods...whereas some high impact factor journals focus on advancements in methods for Healthcare. Sorry if my English isn't that good